# Allow FTP User to modify contents of folder owned by Oracle

Tags: ftp

I have a Oracle Linux VM with Oracle DB and APEX installed.  The db is in `/home/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1`. In this folder there are folders specific to the APEX products: `/Product_1`, `/Product_2`, etc

Currently files are added to these product folders using FTP with the Oracle user. Meaning anyone with these credentials can login to the box and do a lot of things they maybe shouldn't.

How can I set up an ftpuser

```
$ usermod -d /home/oracle/products/11.2.0/dbhome_1/ ftpuser
```

so that ftpuser can ONLY read and write files to the sub folders, bearing in mind these have to be owned by Oracle so APEX can read the files in these folders and import them into the database?

Every post I've seen says to create a new folder for the ftpuser to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless APEX is specifically enforcing the ownership requirement (which would be stupid), the files themselves would only need to be readable by Oracle. If APEX needs to move away or delete the files after the import, then the *directory the files are in* needs to be writeable by APEX.

I don't know APEX, but I would consider setting up the home directory of the FTP user as

```
usermod -d /home/ftpuser ftpuser
```

then moving the APEX product folders to `/home/ftpuser/Product_1` etc. and then creating symbolic links like this:

```
ln -s /home/ftpuser/Product_1 /home/oracle/products/11.2.0/dbhome_1/Product_1
```

so that `/home/oracle/products/11.2.0/dbhome_1/Product_1 -> /home/ftpuser/Product_1`.

Now, the ftpuser can be chrooted so it will see its home directory as `/` over FTP, and so it will be completely unable to access the actual `/home/oracle/...` directory tree at all. APEX, on the other hand, should treat the symbolic link as equivalent to the real directory (unless it specifically checks for symbolic links) and access the product subfolders through the links.

The `ftpuser` should have its own group, i.e. first `groupadd ftpuser` if necessary, then `usermod -g ftpuser ftpuser`. The `oracle` user should also be a secondary member of the `ftpuser` group: `usermod -a -G ftpuser oracle` or `gpasswd -a oracle ftpuser`.

Permissions and ownerships:

- `/home/ftpuser` could be owned by root but needs to be accessible by ftpuser, so if ftpuser has a group dedicated to it, it could be `chown root:ftpuser` and `chmod 0750` (`drwxr-x---`) for maximal restrictiveness.
- Product sub-folders like `/home/ftpuser/Product_1` can be owned by user `oracle`, group `ftpuser` and writable by both user and group. A setgid bit ensures the group will be set correctly. So `chown oracle:ftpuser` and `chmod 2770` (`drwxrws---`).
- If possible, the FTP server should be configured to **not** preserve the client-side file permissions; it should enforce a standard umask of 022 or 002 instead. As a result, the files added to the product sub-folders will be owned by `ftpuser`, group `ftpuser` and permissions 0644 or 0664 (`-rw-r--r--` or `-rw-rw-r--` respectively).

Since `oracle` will be a member of the `ftpuser` group, it will be able to access `/home/ftpuser`. Since the product subfolders are owned by `oracle`, even if the `ftpuser` manages to create files with incorrect permissions, `oracle` will be able to at least delete them anyway, and will always be able to create new files if needed. And since the files in the product subfolder will be readable by all who can access the folder, reading and importing the files should not be a problem at all; if `umask 002` is enforced by the FTP server, `oracle` will be able to even write into the files if needed.

**Note:** the FTP user will see the product subfolder `Product_1` as `~/Product_1`, or even as `/Product_1` if the chroot functionality of the FTP server is used. The APEX configuration will probably not need to be changed at all, since the symbolic links will allow the existing pathnames to be used as-is (unless APEX specifically checks for and rejects symbolic links).

The actual disk space for the product sub-folders will now be consumed at `/home/ftpuser/Product_1` etc., not in the `/home/oracle/...` directory hierarchy. If this is a problem, you could use Linux bind mounts in place of symbolic links, by first creating empty directories `/home/ftpuser/Product_1` etc. as mount points, then adding lines like this in your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
/home/oracle/products/11.2.0/dbhome_1/Product_1 /home/ftpuser/Product_1 none bind 0 0
```

After rebooting or doing `mount -a`, the actual product subfolders should now also be accessible under `/home/ftpuser/`. Note that unlike symbolic links, this use of bind mounts may cause each product subfolder to consume double the backup capacity, unless you exclude the extra copy from your backups.

Comment: wow.  Thanks very much for that very descriptive answer telcoM.  I will read that again on Monday without the help of my Saturday night Strongbow.